# Time series past weeks revenue calculation

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data set

```
Customer Week   Revenue 
A        201701   100 
A        201702   99
A        201703   120
A        201704   110
```

I need to create the following variables for each customer week in SQL

```
Customer Week   
past 4 weeks revenue 
past 7 weeks revenue  
past 11 weeks revenue and so on till past 51 weeks revenue.
```

Here's the approach which I am trying to use, the issue with this approach is that for each past n weeks, I would have create seperate tables and join all those together.

```
select customer, sum(revenue) 

(select customer, cust2.revenue
from customer1 join customer2 
on customerid = customerid
where cust1.week <= cust2.week + 51)
```

Is there a more efficient way of calculating past `4,7,11,15,18,21 till 51` weeks in SQL? I am using spark sql.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions.  Assuming you have one row per customer/week:

```
select t.*,
       sum(revenue) over (partition by customer order by week rows between 3 preceding and current row) as revenue_4week,
       sum(revenue) over (partition by customer order by week rows between 6 preceding and current row) as revenue_7week,
from t;
```